# Compares two column based on the value of a third column's value

Tags: vba, excel

What I want to do is create a macro to look at a column (AF) and based on that value, compare column (BI), (BJ), and/or (BK) together and if its false, highlight the compared cells in yellow. I know that's a little hard to follow but this example should help clarify:

My Sheet has the following columns:

```
Column AF    Column BI    Column BJ    Column BK
PRODUCT      Height       Length       Width
```

I need a macro to look at the product type and compare the dimensions for that product as follows:

```
  - If product = A, then Length = Width, if not then highlight Length and Width Cells
  - If product = B then Length > Width, if not then highlight Length and Width Cells
  - If product = C then Width > Height < Length, if not highlight Length, Width, and Height cells
  - If product - D then Width = Length < Height, if not highlight Width, Length, and/or Height
```

My Data starts on row 3 and ends at row 5002.

I have tried researching this and was only able to find solutions that compare two cells then write a third column. I could combine an IF formula and conditional formatting to achieve this but I don't want to have this run all the time as the sheet will be sorted and color coded. I plan to place this macro into a command button.

Comment: I'd look into Conditional Formatting.

Comment: @Chrismas007 Thank you for your reply. My concern with that is that I already have a macro command button that highlights entire rows based on the product type, then it sorts by cell color. I'm concerned that the conditional format may case inconsistencies with the sorting function of my existing macro. This sheet will be used by a wide variety of users with different skill levels so I need a solution that is very user friendly so simply turning the conditional format on and off wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: Then use a different color to not screw up your filter.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest to combine `Statements` such as `Select Case`, `If...Then...Else`, together with Operators `And`, `Or`. See the following pages:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251599.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251356.aspx

After which you should be able to write something that resembles this:
*(Code below is just a sample, it will not work)*

```
Select Case Product
Case A
    If Length <> Width Then
        Rem Highlight Length And Width  Cells
    End If
Case B
    If Length <= Width Then
        Rem Insert here the code to highlight Length And Width Cells
    End If
Case C
    If Width <= Height And Height >= Length Then
        Rem Insert here the code to highlight Length, Width, and Height cells
    End If
Case D
    If Width <> Length And Length >= Height Then
        Rem Insert here the code to highlight Width, Length, and/or Height
    End If
End Sub
```

In case you don’t know to highlight the Width, Length and Height Cells; I suggest to do it manually while recording a macro, this shall give a good starting point.

Comment: That framework looks like a great start, thank you. I was able to record the highlighting, but I'm not sure how to change the range so that it will highlight the Length and Width column for the same row of the Product that started the Case statement. Could you assist with this?

`Range("BJ4:BK4").Select
          With Selection.Interior
         .Pattern = xlSolid
         .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
         .Color = 65535
         .TintAndShade = 0
         .PatternTintAndShade = 0
         End With`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to work with objects, defining variables for the Data range, each row being validated, the position of the fields to validate, etc. see below code with comments

```
Sub Highlight_Cells_based_Comparison()
Dim rData As Range
Dim rRow As Range
Dim rCllsUnion As Range
Rem Set variables to hold Fields position within the DATA range
Dim bPosProd As Byte, bPosHght As Byte, bPosLeng As Byte, bPosWdth As Byte
Rem Set variables to hold Fields values
Rem (data type Variant as don't know type of values these fields are holding, change as appropriated)
Rem see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251528.aspx)
Dim sProd As String, vHght As Variant, vLeng As Variant, vWdth As Variant
Dim lRow As Long

    Rem Set Range (assuming it goes from column C to BK - change as needed)
    Rem Not starting from column A on porpuse
    Set rData = ActiveSheet.Range("C3:BK5002")

    Rem Get Fields position from Header row
    Rem Suggest to use this method instead of hard coding columns
    On Error Resume Next
    With rData
        bPosProd = WorksheetFunction.Match("PRODUCT", .Rows(1), 0)
        bPosHght = WorksheetFunction.Match("Height", .Rows(1), 0)
        bPosLeng = WorksheetFunction.Match("Length", .Rows(1), 0)
        bPosWdth = WorksheetFunction.Match("Width", .Rows(1), 0)
    End With
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo 0

    Rem Loop thru each row excluding header           
    For lRow = 2 To rData.Rows.Count
            Set rRow = rData.Rows(lRow)
            With rRow
                Rem Get Row Field values
                sProd = .Cells(bPosProd).Value2
                vHght = .Cells(bPosHght).Value2
                vLeng = .Cells(bPosLeng).Value2
                vWdth = .Cells(bPosWdth).Value2                    

            Select Case sProd
            Case A 'Change value of A as required
            Rem If product = A, then Length = Width, if not then highlight Length and Width Cells
            Rem If Length <> Width Then Highlight Length And Width  'Cells
                If vLeng <> vWdth Then
                    Set rCllsUnion = Union(.Cells(bPosLeng), .Cells(bPosWdth))
                    Rem Suggest to use a subroutine for this piece as it's a repetitive task
                    Rem see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251648.aspx
                    GoSub CllsUnion_Highlight
                End If

            Case B
                Rem repeat as in Case A with required changes
            Case C
                '...
            Case D
                '...
    End Select: End With: Next


Exit Sub
Rem Subroutine to highlight cells
CllsUnion_Highlight:
    With rCllsUnion.Interior
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Return

End Sub
```